# Ldap - centos: cannot create home folder on login

Tags: file-permissions, centos-7, ldap, home-directory

I added
`session     optional      pam_mkhomedir.so umask=0047 skel=/etc/skel`
on my
`/etc/pam.d/system-auth`
but when I try to do
`su user`
I got something like 
`Impossible to create and initialize directory '/ldap-home/user`

NOTE:
directory `/ldap-home` exists

Edit:

Tryed logging in by a 'fresh' TTY (typing `^F<N>`) it creates the home with no problem.

Comment: Are you using SELinux? Is `/ldap-home` a local filesystem or a network mount?

Comment: `/ldap-home` is local, selinux is enabled